# Terraform's external data source: STDOUT syntax unclear

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform

I would like to use terraform's external data source to identify certain AWS EC2 instances:

```
data "external" "monitoring_instances" {
  program = ["bash", "${path.module}/../bash/tf_datasource_monitoring.sh"]

  query = {
    env = var.env_stage
  }
}
```

The bash script is using AWS CLI to return a list of instance IDs.

But I keep receiving this `Error: command "bash" produced invalid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type string`

I don't understand what the expected syntax of my script's STDOUT would be for terraform to understand the result.

So let's assume the script is supposed to return 3 instance IDs `i-1`, `i-2` and `i-3`.

What would be the correct JSON syntax to be returned to terraform?

Examples, that do NOT work:

```
{
"instances": [
  "i-1",
  "i-2",
  "i-3"
]
}
```

```
[
  "i-1",
  "i-2",
  "i-3"
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known issue in Terraform for `provider-external`: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-external/issues/2. It was opened a while ago, unfortunately is still present for latest version (Terraform v1.011).

You may want to avoid returning JSON objects which contain arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, while executing a python script to generate a dynamic bigquery schema, which is per definition an array of JSONs.

I solved it, by implementing a wrapper JSON with the schema as a string value (see dummy code below).

```
# get_dynamic_bigquery_schema.py
import json

bigquery_schema = [
       {"name": "int_field", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE", "description": "int_field"},
       {"name": "int_field_repeated", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "REPEATED", "description": "int_field_repeated"}
   ]

wrapper_json = {'actual_output': str(json.dumps(bigquery_schema))}

print(json.dumps(wrapper_json))
```

which I can then access within terraform

```
# main.tf
data "external" "bigquery_schema" {
  program = ["python", "${path.module}/get_dynamic_bigquery_schema.py"]
}
locals {
  bigquery_schema= data.external.bigquery_schema.result['actual_output']
}
```